# Python read text file from second line to fifteenth

Tags: python, file, readlines

I have a text file and I need to read from the seconds line to to 15th line including.
I've tried some methods but no method worked for me...
I'd be happy if anyone could help me ...
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('filename') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 1, 16):
        print line
```

Comment: +1 best way to do this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Why is it the best way? Because `islice` uses generator expressions?

Comment: @thefourtheye `islice` is a fast and pythonic way to get a slice from an iterator, It does loops over the iterator but that happens internally at C speed.

Comment: +1 This seems very elegant. I wasn't aware of `islice` before. `itertools` is quite the treasure chest!

Answer (score 9):

If the file isn't very big:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    print f.readlines()[1:15]
```

Comment: If the file is huge this will load everything into memory.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just read the lines and take the ones you need

For example:

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as text_file:
    data = text_file.readlines()
```

now `data[1]` will be second line and `data[14]` will be 15th, so you can slice it as such `data[1:14]`

Then you can put them into a variable and that's it

Comment: Open files in a `with` block.

Answer (score 4):

[Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422155/771848) is definitely a more pythonic and clean approach.

---

Alternatively, you can use `enumerate()`:

```
with open("file", 'r') as f:
    print [x for i, x in enumerate(f) if 1 <= i <= 15]
```

Note, that this will loop over all lines in a file. It's better to break the loop after the 15th line, like this:

```
with open("file", 'r') as f:
    for i, x in enumerate(f):
        if 1 <= i <= 15:
            print x
        elif i > 15:
            break
```